# Redshift COPY from AWS S3 directory full of CSV files

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to perform a COPY query in Redshift in order to load different .csv files stored in a AWS S3 path (let's say `s3://bucket/path/csv/`). The .csv files in that path contain a date in their filenames (i.e.: `s3://bucket/path/csv/file_20200605.csv`, `s3://bucket/path/csv/file_20200604.csv`,...) since they the data inside them corresponds to the data for a specific day. My question here is (since the order of loading the files matter), will Redshift load these files in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 4):

The COPY command leverages the Amazon Redshift massively parallel processing (MPP) architecture to read and load data in **parallel** from files in an Amazon S3 bucket.

so regards to your question, the files will load in parallel.